# Existence of fixed simple closed curve by polynomials

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems, curves, complex-dynamics, fixed-points

As the problem mentioned in the title, I wonder that if there exists a simple closed curve on the complex plane which is not circle that can be fixed by a non-linear polynomial with complex coefficients($P(C)=C$, $C$ for the curve and $P$ for the polynomial) ?

I have asked others about this problem, and some said that this is related to dynamical system.

Comment: "that can be fixed": what does that mean ??

Comment: Why do you specify *non-linear* polynomial ?

Comment: For the first question, I have edited the problem to make it clear.

Comment: And for the second question, that is because you can draw a square and rotate it by $\pi/2$ which can be represented as linear polynomial.

Comment: So $C$ is a simple closed curve (in a plane?), and $P(x,y)=(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials in $x$ and $y$? With real coefficients, or complex, or something else?

Comment: Are you in $\mathbb R^2$ or in $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: in $\mathbb C$, sorry for the not clear problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The Julia set of a polynomial is always fixed in exactly the sense that you say and can often be a fractal, simple, closed curve.

The Julia set is, by definition, the closure of the set of repelling periodic points of the polynomial. For example, if $P(z)=z^2$, then the Julia set of $P$ is exactly the unit circle. If $P(z) = z^2 + c$, however, where $c$ is close to zero, then the Julia set is a somewhat distorted version of the unit circle with a fractal structure. If $c=-1/2$, for example, then the Julia set looks like so:

[image]

Thus, that simple closed curve is fixed by $P(z)=z^2-1/2$.

Comment: I wonder if P is a bijection on that curve.

Comment: @SteveCheng鄭宗弘 No. In fact, it is two-to-one, just like $z^2$ on the unit circle.

Comment: No - $f$ acts [transitively](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_transitivity) on the Julia set.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the question...

Comment: Since the Julia set may be a union of some disconnected components. I also wonder if there exists a Julia set J(f) that consisted of several components and a connected subset S of J(f) that f(S)=S?

Answer (score 2):

Closed [invariant](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/def_cqp#Invariant_3) curves :

- orbits  inside [main chessboard box](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/pcheckerboard)) in the parabolic case - second image below ( are invariant under proper power of the map) and lay on the simply closed invariant curves
- orbits inside [Siegel disc](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/siegel) and [first image below](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Siegel_disk_for_c_%3D_-0.749998153581339_%2B0.001569040474910_i.png)
- a subset of the Julia set generated by Herman’s Blaschke product has invariant circles - see [GEOMETRY OF THE JULIA SET FOR SOME MAPS WITH INVARIANT CIRCLES by Kimberly A. Roth](http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/roth/proof.pdf)
- ( thx to Claude) on [the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) : 2 [external rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ray) landing on the same point and [the point at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity) form closed curve, see image by [Wolf Jung](http://www.mndynamics.com/indexp.html) - third image

All images made with program Mandel by Wolf Jung

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some collections of external rays invariant under one function, eg the external rays at angles (measured in turns) $\frac{1}{7}$ $\frac{2}{7}$ $\frac{4}{7}$ are permuted cyclically by $f_c(z) = z^2 + c$, are also each individually invariant under another function, eg $f_c^{\circ 3}$.

Comment: @Claude : Ok , but they are not closed.

Comment: @Claude Ok, they are closed on the sphere. Thx